# google.com vs google.com.xx showing different results for sitelinks

Tags: google-search, sitelinks

We have a site where we want to make sure that google sitelinks should show up as can be seen in screen below:

[image: Google search showing sitelinks]

This is working fine as long as we perform the search on specific localized google domain such as **google.com.pk** (notice the ending prefix of country in url) but when we perform the search on main google domain **google.com**, sitelinks aren't showing up at all as can be seen in below screen:

[image: Google search not showing sitelinks]

I know main google domain and country specific domains show up different results.

My question is how do I make sure sitelinks also show up on main google domain not just country-specific google domain?

Comment: it is regardless of whether iam logged in or in private/ignitio mode or locale settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you can do to "force" sitelinks to appear in the results. As you state, "[the] main google domain and country specific domains show up different results."

And whether Google shows sitelinks will depend on the particular search phrase.

However, if I do the same search on `google.com` **I do see the sitelinks**, as in your first screenshot. This is regardless of whether I am logged into Google or whether I'm using incognito/private browsing. So, maybe this is a localisation issue? However, if I do a search on `google.co.uk` (the result does appear to be located in "London") I do not get the full sitelinks - just the short version, "Donate to ... - Contact us - Our story").

Comment: yes it is regardless of whether iam logged in or in private/ignitio mode or locale settings.

Comment: But like I say, "I do see the sitelinks", so from where I'm sitting it is working as intended. (You do seem to get the "small version" of the sitelinks just below the address.)